# What equipment do I need to buy to start making beer?

Tags: beer, equipment, cider, beginner

What is the minimum equipment to start brewing some good beer at home?

Comment: These are all very good answers, and complete. Don't let these shopping lists detour you from starting your first batch. If you can boil water, you can make beer. Beer has been made for thousands of years often in clay pots with magical sticks that unknowingly held a families yeast culture.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

### Brewing day

- **Sanitizer** - To sanitize all of your equipment.
- **6 gallon fermenter** - For primary fermentation.
- **Funnel or Tubing** - To transfer from the brew kettle to the fermenter (pour or siphon)
- **+3 gallon brew kettle** - For boiling the mixture and making wort
- **Thermometer** - To monitor the temperature of the wort
- **Hydrometer** - To test the original gravity of your batch
- **Paddle/spoon** - Something to stir the boil with
- **Timer** - You need to know how long to boil and when to add ingredients
- **Ice** - After brewing, you will need to cool the wort. Putting the kettle in ice water to cool it faster

### Transferring day (if you transfer)

- **Sanitizer** - To sanitize all of your equipment
- **5 gallon fermenter** - For secondary fermentation
- **Siphon tubing** - To siphon the beer from your primary fermenter to your secondary
- **Fermenter airlock** - To lock oxygen out of fermenter while allowing other gases exit

### Bottling day

- **Sanitizer** - To sanitize all equipment and bottles
- **Bottles/caps** - Make sure they are not twist-off bottles
- **Bottle capper** - How else did you expect the caps to get on?
- **Bottle brush** - If the bottles aren't clean, you'll need to clean them
- **Siphon tubing** - To siphon beer from fermenter to bottles
- **Thermometer** - To check temperature when recording final gravity
- **Hydrometer** - To measure the final gravity
- **Priming sugar** - Used to carbonate the beer while in the bottle
- **Bottling wand** - This allows you to easily control the flow while bottling

### Nice to haves

- **Auto siphon** - This will make siphoning a breeze
- **Log sheet(s)** - Keep track of what you're doing. This is science after all!

  - http://cdn2.brewersfriend.com/brewersfriend_extractsheet.pdf
  - https://web.archive.org/web/20160804111221/http://homebrewmanual.com/media/Home-Brewing-Record-Sheets.pdf
- **Checklist** - Don't forget anything!

  - http://cdn2.brewersfriend.com/brewersfriend_checklist_extract.pdf

This list is mostly if you plan on doing extract brewing. You might need extra equipment for a full-grain setup. Also, this assumes you are using a kit that comes with necessary ingredients and a muslin bag.

Brew kits, which should supply much of the equipment, are available from various homebrew shops.

Comment: Nice List. Perhaps I'm a terrible person but I've been too lazy to move to a secondary fermenter in the past. I don't think I'd say it was strictly necessary.

Comment: Great list, maybe add a bottle brush & spoon

Comment: Nice list. A beginner might be able to get by without glass bottles, caps and capper: http://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/189/are-plastic-fizzy-drink-bottles-an-acceptable-substitute-for-glass-bottles

Comment: Cool answer. Go !

Comment: This is not really equipment, but I would add some sort of brewer's worksheet, note book, or way to keep record.  There are several nice worksheets available in PDF format online.

Comment: @ChinoBrews If you can suggest a nice PDF I will add it to the list. Good suggestion

Comment: @ JoePhillips Outstanding. For a simple brew day log sheet for a beginner extract brewer, [this sheet from Brewer’s Friend](http://cdn2.brewersfriend.com/brewersfriend_extractsheet.pdf) would be great. This [log sheet from Home Brew Manual](http://homebrewmanual.com/media/Home-Brewing-Record-Sheets.pdf) is only slightly more advanced. Also, Brewer’s Friend has a nice [brew day checklist](http://cdn2.brewersfriend.com/brewersfriend_checklist_extract.pdf), although it may deviate some from the instructions that come with a specific recipe kit.

Comment: I couldn't help but notice that you have no equipment for cooling the beer under brewing day and am wondering if it is left out on purpose due to it only being the minimum..

Comment: @Sander Nope. Cooling equipment should be mentioned. I'll edit.

Comment: Do you not need an airlock for the primary?

Comment: @MildFuzz We usually use a blowoff tube for primary for the first couple days

Comment: why is that? additional force?

Comment: @MildFuzz Additional volume and sometimes there are big chunks of wort that will clog up a regular airlock

Answer (score 24):

I would point you to the Basic Starter Kit from Northern Brewer:

[Beer Making Kits](http://www.northernbrewer.com/brewing/starter-kits/basic-starter-kit.html)

Some items are probably not STRICTLY needed, but for $80 you definitely get all the gear you would need to get started.

Comment: And it includes an auto-siphon. Not *necessary* but greatly simplifies racking.

Answer (score 16):

Assuming you're beginning from concentrated malt or a kit, and can figure out how to boil water on your own,

**The bare minimum:**

- 5 gallon plastic (food grade
  container) with lid.
- Airlock for same.
- Bottles, and appropriate
  closures for them.
- Plastic hose for
  siphoning off of finished product.
- Disinfectant (chlorine or sulfite)

**Recommended:**

- 5 Gallon glass carboy (secondary fermentation and settling)
- Hydrometer (for measuring specify gravity/sugar/alchohol content)
- Various gadgetry for siphon - A raiser in the fermenter end to keep out the lees, and a bottling attachment at the bottle end (basically a plastic tube with a ballstop in the bottom)

**Optional:**

- Filtration device
- Pumps

You can make a decent beer with just the minimum.
Add the rest as time and budget allow.   Each time you go to the supplier, buy one more thing to make the job easier.

Answer (score 7):

Don't underestimate the affect good temperature control will have on your beers.

While not *strictly* necessary I believe to make good beer you should invest in some kind of fridge/freezer with a temperature controller. Often this can be done fairly cheaply if you can get hold of an unwanted fridge and pick up a cheap temperature controller from eBay or similar.

Before moving from kit to all grain brewing adding consistent temperature control during fermentation was the single thing that made the biggest improvement to my beers.

Comment: Not necessary.  If you must keep your beer cool in hot weather, place the fermenter in a bucket of water, and place 2 litre bottles of frozen water in to keep the temperature down.  Obviously you need a few of these ice packs in rotation through the freezer and the cold water bath...   However, if you're making Lager styles, and/or live in a really hot place (Florida?!) rather than the nice cool temperate United Kingdom, Simon may have a point.

Answer (score 4):

While these are nice lists I would like to point out that you do not ***need*** a 5 gallon bucket and carboy.  I like to experiment with new recipes using a two gallon bucket and an old one gallon apple cider jug. Cheap, easy, and provides 8 bottles of beer in much less (brew day) time than a five gallon batch.