# Must-have supplies for making one's own beer?

Tags: equipment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What equipment do I need to buy to start homebrewing?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-equipment-do-i-need-to-buy-to-start-homebrewing)

What are the must-have supplies for brewing your own beer? In addition to ingredients, what types of containers, tools, gadgets, and goodies do you find useful?

Comment: Apparently while I was waiting for a tag to assign this to, someone asked a similar question... I'm looking for both equipment and recommended ingredients...

Comment: flagged as duplicate.  I'd re-ask this as community wiki "Helpful Gadgetry and Doo-Dads"

Comment: Wiki is a mod-only feature now...